# Angular - How to put one single object<T> in a BehaviorSubject<T[]>

Tags: html, angular, api, http, rxjs

I have a data table populated by a `BehaviorSubject<Sequence[]>`, here's how it works:

```
//sequencesService

findSequences(pageIndex: number, pageSize: number, rrc: string, datiForm: FormComponent): Observable<PaginatedResult>{
    return this.http.get<PaginatedResult>('https://bgpie.net/api/rrc/' + rrc + '/sequence', { params});
    }

//dataSource
export class SequencesDataSource implements DataSource<Sequence> {

    private sequencesSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Sequence[]>([]);

    private loadingSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    public loading$ = this.loadingSubject.asObservable();

    public length = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

loadSequences(pageIndex: number,
                  pageSize: number,
                  rrc: string,
                  datiForm: FormComponent) {

        this.loadingSubject.next(true);

        this.sequencesService.findSequences(pageIndex, pageSize, rrc, datiForm).pipe(
                finalize(() => this.loadingSubject.next(false)),
                tap(x => this.length.next(x.total))
            )
            .subscribe((sequences: PaginatedResult) => {
            this.sequencesSubject.next(sequences.items);
        });}
    }

//PaginatedResult
export interface PaginatedResult{
  readonly items: Sequence[];
  readonly total: number;
}
```

I would like to be able to filter the table using the sequence Id as a criteria. This means that only one sequence would have to be shown. While the method `findSequences` calls for an API containing an array of sequences, the method below calls for an API with a single sequence, as it should be:

```
getSequence(id: string): Observable<Sequence> {
        return this.http.get<Sequence>('https://bgpie.net/api/sequence/' + id);
    }
```

The problem is that I can't use an observable of type `Sequence` to populate a `BehaviorSubject<Sequence[]>`.
I tried returning an observable of type `Sequence[]` (like in the code below) and then subscribing to it but it doesn't work.

```
//sequencesService
getSequenceFilter(id: string): Observable<Sequence[]> {
        return this.http.get<Sequence[]>('https://bgpie.net/api/sequence/' + id);
    }

//dataSource
loadSequence(datiForm: FormComponent){
        this.loadingSubject.next(true);

        this.sequencesService.getSequenceFilter(datiForm.sequenceId).pipe(
            finalize(() => this.loadingSubject.next(false)),
            finalize(() => this.length.next(1))
        )
        .subscribe((sequence: Sequence[]) => this.sequencesSubject.next(sequence))
```

Comment: Have `getSequence(id: string)` return `Observable<Sequence>` and in `loadSequence` method change to`.pipe(......., map(sequence => [sequence]), tap(sequence => this.sequencesSubject.next(sequence))).subscribe()`

Comment: Thanks it works, if you post an answer I can mark it as a solution

Comment: Glad to hear. I just did. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following simple changes:

1. Have `getSequence(id: string)` return `Observable<Sequence>`
2. In `loadSequence` method change to `.pipe(......., map(sequence => [sequence]), tap(sequence => this.sequencesSubject.next(sequence))).subscribe()`

Answer (score 1):

you could next unique sequence instance as array

`this.sequencesSubject.next([sequence])`

instead of single object

`this.sequencesSubject.next(sequence)`

Full function modified

```
loadSequence(datiForm: FormComponent){
        this.loadingSubject.next(true);

        this.sequencesService.getSequenceFilter(datiForm.sequenceId).pipe(
            finalize(() => this.loadingSubject.next(false)),
            finalize(() => this.length.next(1))
        )
        .subscribe((sequence: Sequence) => this.sequencesSubject.next([sequence]))
```